# Get records for yesterday from list c#

Tags: c#, list, datetime, filter, datatable

I set up a list with 7 columns and Thousands of rows.
I also have a data table with the same data (yes, redundant).
What I am trying to do is get all the records related to yesterdays date.

I've started a few queries on the data table with no success.  It keeps on coming up empty. Same with the list.

Below is all my code for the table/list.

```
     DataTable dtTesting = new DataTable();
            List<string>[] listA = new List<string> [8];
            listA[0] = new List<string>();
            listA[1] = new List<string>();
            listA[2] = new List<string>();
            listA[3] = new List<string>();
            listA[4] = new List<string>();
            listA[5] = new List<string>();
            listA[6] = new List<string>();
            listA[7] = new List<string>();

            dtTesting.Columns.Add("Over2Minutes", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("AgentName", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(DateTime ));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("Direction", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("CallTo", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("ManagerName", typeof(string));
            dtTesting.Columns.Add("Duration", typeof(string));

            // List<string> listE = new List<string>();
            //List<string> listF = new List<string>();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                DataRow data = dtTesting.NewRow();
                data["Over2Minutes"] = values[0];
                data["AgentName"] = values[1];
                data["PhoneNumber"] = values[2];
                data["DateTime"] = values[3];
                data["Direction"] = values[4];
                data["CallTo"] = values[5];
                data["ManagerName"] = values[6];
                data["Duration"] = values[7];

                listA[0].Add(values[0]);
                listA[1].Add(values[1]);
                listA[2].Add(values[2]);
                listA[3].Add(values[3]);
                listA[4].Add(values[4]);
                listA[5].Add(values[5]);
                listA[6].Add(values[6]);
                listA[7].Add(values[7]);


            } 
            //start of filters

            DataTable filtered = new DataTable();
            DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

            //List<string> listBD = new List<string>();
           // listBD.AddRange(listB);
         //   listBD.AddRange(listD);
           // 


            if (cbDayList.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                  var FilteredData =   

                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Data To Show");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Most of your code isn't relevant. Just describe your table's structure instead of pasting the code that constructs and populates it.

Comment: Please provide minimal, verifiable, runnable code.

Comment: Also, could you provide any filtering code that you have used? As for now, we don't have any information what queries have you tried.

Comment: Where do you filter the data? On the List or on the DataTable? This is important because you have a `List<string>` for a datatable column that is a `DateTime` and filtering on the first is very dependant on how do you format the date string. As now, the date is stored using your localization of a datetime

Comment: Wow, I got a lot of responses faster than expected. My apologies for the minimal description. The display above was to show that I have both an active table and list I can pull from.

The code I've tried to filter: dtTesting.Select("DateTime >= #" + yesterday + "# AND date <= #" + today + "#"); 
I've tried variations of the above.

They Key code I'm trying to figure out is this:
When cbDayList index value is set to 0, filter the datatable -or- List (whichever is better) and set the results to a new DataTable (or List) so I can query that new DataTable (or List)

Comment: In that context the datetime variable should be converted to a string with ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the DataTable rows according to a particular data you use the Select method of the DataTable. But, being the FilterExpression of the Select method a string, you are forced to convert the DateTime variables to a string. And this is where the problem begin.

You cannot use the default conversion of a DateTime to a string because in case of DateTime the FilterExpression requires the date to be expressed according to the InvariantCulture format. `"M/d/yyyy"`

```
 var FilteredData = dtSettings.Select("DateTime >= #" + 
                                      yesterday.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + 
                                      "# AND date <= #" + 
                                      today.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#");
```

By the way, albeit improbable this query gets also the records stored exactly  at midnight. Probably you need `< today.ToString("M/d/yyyy")`

Another way to reach your goal is through the IEnumerable extension Where (Linq namespace)

```
 var  FilteredData = dtSettings.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("DateTime") >= yesterday &&
                          x.Field<DateTime>("DateTime") < today);
```